# Changes on my HSQLDB are inconsistent

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, database-administration

I've been trying to learn how to use HSQLDB but it seems like any changes I make are acknowledged and then either ignored or done incorrectly.  For instance, I created a new user (internal_admin) as SA but after attempting to log in as this user I get the following error:

`not found: internal_admin`

Command used to make user: `create user internal_admin password somepassword ADMIN;`

To add to my issues, I changed the password of SA to a randomized password that I copied from a .txt file (to ensure the password was entered correctly) but after trying to log in with the exact same password on SA I get an `invalid authorization specification`.  Checking the logs, all commands I sent went through successfully and were logged, but the changes are not being reflected.  Is HSQLDB just absolutely, unforgivably awful or am I doing something wrong?  I've tried restarting the db but it makes no difference.

Command used to change password: `Alter User SA set password somepassword;`

I should add that I'm doing this testing on my local computer, not on a remote or dedicated server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB enforces case sensitivity for user names and passwords. You need to use relevant quote characters for user name and password to make them in the exact case you entered..

```
create user "internal_admin" password 'somepassword' ADMIN;
```